# How do I solve type 'MappedListIterable<DocumentSnapshot, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>' errors

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using FutureBuilder to Query Firestore for the **documentID** in one collection then **pass the documentID to another collection.**The relevant error-causing widget was**FutureBuilder**
What could be the issue? I've checked the code I'm not sure maybe its the format.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
      children: [
```

The first Future builder retrieves the documentID in Cart

```
        FutureBuilder(              //                                    <<=========FutureBuilder
            future: usersref
            .document().
            collection("Cart")
            .getDocuments(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
              {
                return ListView(                               //  <<===  ListView
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 108.0,
                    bottom: 12.0,
                  ),
                  children: snapshot
                  .data.
                  documents.map((document) {          //        <<===snapshot map
                    return FutureBuilder(                
                      future: productsRef
                          .document(widget.shopname)
                          .collection("products")
```

Then It's passed below to another collection reference

```
                          .document(document.documentID)  //<<===documentID
                          .get(),
                      // ignore: missing_return
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return Scaffold(
                            body: Center(
                              child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}"),
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                        if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                            ConnectionState.waiting) {
                          Center(
                            child: Text("Waiting...'"),
                          );
                        }
                        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) { 
                          Map _productMap = document.data.documents(); //       <<<======== Map
                          return Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  width: 90,
                                  height: 90,
                                  child: ClipRRect(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
```

From the collection reference, Im querying the data.
child: Image.network(

```
                                      "${_productMap['images'][0]}",
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            );
                        }},
                    );
                  }),
                );
              }
            })
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i see multiple things that can go wrong. I'm not sure why you're nesting multiple FutureBuilders in a parent FutureBuilder. Scaffold should be on top level, now you have multiple of them.

The error you get is in the `ListViews children`. It expects widgets but you're mapping it to another FutureBuilder.

```
snapshot.data.documents.map((document) {          
    return FutureBuilder(                
         future: productsRef
                    .document(widget.shopname)
                    .collection("products").document(document.documentID)
                    .get(),
```

the snapshot has all the info you need so try this:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
  itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => Text(snapshot.data.documents[i].documentID) // <-docID
```

Also, i generally use futurebuilder to check the state of the user, to get the documents, use StreamBuilder

Comment: I see, any suggestions? I have to retrieve the ID still